# Example of two real monic polynomials with roots contained in the unit disk, with a convex combination of the two having a root outside the unit disk

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Referring to [ON THE ZEROS OF CONVEX COMBINATIONS OF POLYNOMIALS H. J. FELL](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-89/issue-1/On-the-zeros-of-convex-combinations-of-polynomials/pjm/1102779366.pdf), theorem 4 states an upper bound for the modulus of the roots of the convex combination of two real monic polynomials whose roots are contained in the unit disk, which is equal to $\frac{cos(\frac{\pi}{2n})}{sin(\frac{\pi}{2n})}$ with n being their degree. So as n > 2, we'd have an upper bound strictly bigger than one.
The thing is I'm struggling to come up with an example of such polynomials whom a convex combination has one root with modulus bigger than one. Can someone please give me an example of such polynomials ?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

- For real polynomials, take $P_0(x)=(x-1)^3$ and $P_1(x)=(x+1)^3$. Their roots are $\pm 1$ on the unit circle, but $P_{1/2}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(P_0(x) + P_1(x)\right)=x^3 + 3x$ has roots $\pm i \sqrt{3}$ outside it.
- For complex polynomials, let $\omega = \frac{1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and take $P_0(x)=(x-\omega)^3$ and $P_1(x)=(x-\overline{\omega})^3$. The roots $\omega, \overline\omega$ are on the unit circle, but $P_{1/2}(x)$ has a root outside it [equal to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x+-+%28%281+%2B+i+sqrt%283%29%29%2F2%29%29%5E3+%2B+%28x+-+%28%281+-+i+sqrt%283%29%29%2F2%29%29%5E3+%3D+0) $2$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ The latter example has one root moving from $\omega$ to $\bar\omega$ as $t$ moves from $0$ to $1$. FWIW below is the path in the complex plane followed by the root in question. Not only does it go outside the unit circle before returning to it, but actually all proper convex combinations except the endpoints have the root strictly outside the unit disk.

[image]

(*Produced on [sagemath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) with the following quick-and-dirty script*.)

```
w = (1 + i * sqrt(3)) / 2
z = polygen(CC)
o = [CDF(w)]
for k in range(-749,750):
    t = k / 1500
    p = (1 / 2 - t) * (z - w)^3 + (1 / 2 + t) * (z - w.conjugate())^3
    r = p.roots()
    o.append(CDF(r[2][0]))
o.append(CDF(w.conjugate()))
points(o) + circle((0,0), 1, color='lightgray')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. is there an example with polynomials with roots in the open unit disk ?

Comment: @elaoumam Just perturb those polynomials by a small enough amount e.g. using $\pm 0.9$ instead of $\pm 1$ works for the first pair. However, the explicit bounds given in the paper are attained when the roots are _on_ the unit circle, as hinted in the text.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That answers perfectly my question.